# Can't access my ec2 public ip outside rdp

Tags: iis, web-hosting, aws-ec2

I'm using IIS to host my app and I use port 80, on my RDP if I enter the IP address it redirect me to my app but if I use the IP address outside RDP is not working. I checked with XAMPP and is working on same port( not same time) and I can access it outside my RDP. What may be the problem.

[my security group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GUGDt.png)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're hosting your website on an EC2 instance, as well as the IP address, you need to consider the EC2 Security Group(s) attached to your instance.  These are AWS's equivalent of a firewall and control which ports can be accessed from the outside world.

If you don't allow access to port 80 from everywhere, you would be able to access your website from the instance itself as you've said (while connected over Remote Desktop), but now when browsing from another computer.

Check your security group, but for security reasons be sure to only allow access to the specific ports you need, e.g. 80 for HTTP and 443 for HTTPS

See AWS documentation on EC2 security groups at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/working-with-security-groups.html

Comment: my security group is allowing access, i added the photo in question body